# Message: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 or 13 for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu

Running Ubuntu 16 with PHP 7.1 for 6 months after recent update to Ubuntu receive the following error when connecting to MS-SQL Server:

```
Error information: 
SQLSTATE: IMSSP
Code: -49
Message: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 or 13 for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 or 13 for SQL Server for x64: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712
SQLSTATE: IM002
Code: 0
Message: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
```

Sample code:

```
*$serverName = "10.0.9.1";
$connectionOptions = array(
    "Database" => "db",
    "Uid" => "id",
    "PWD" => "pass"
);
//Establishes the connection
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionOptions );*
```

Tried a clean install(s) and with PHP 7.2 same results, but low Linux skill set here.

Comment: Have you installed the new driver in the error message? If not maybe worth installing it first and see if you still get the same error???

Comment: When I install the ODBC Driver it says "already the newest version".

Answer (score 1):

From [New Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 breaks LAMP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48830366/new-microsoft-odbc-driver-17-breaks-lamp-server)

Turns out php_sqlsrv 4.3.* (current stable) install will try to update msodbcsql to 17. The problem is php_sqlsrv needs to be 5+ to work with msodbcsql 17 but it is not released as stable.

Ran:

```
sudo su 
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
exit
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql=13.1.9.0-1 mssql-tools=14.0.6.0-1 unixodbc-dev
```

This fixed the issue, updating again will break it again.