# New Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 breaks LAMP server

Tags: php, odbc, centos7

CentOS 7
Just started using the ODBC Driver 13 and it worked great. A couple of weeks ago version 17 came out and creates conflicts with PHP drivers looking for version 13 **with a fresh install**.

With a new CentOS 7 install I installed 13 explicitly but when I try to install php_sqlsrv it trys to update msodbcsql to 17 (and fails but I didnt want it anyway).

How can I install version 13 with the correct php driver?

Thanks,
Loom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out php_sqlsrv 4.3.* (current stable) install will try to update msodbcsql to 17. The problem is php_sqlsrv needs to be 5+ to work with msodbcsql 17 but it is not released as stable.

Ran:

```
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y  yum install msodbcsql-13.1.9.1-1 mssql-tools-14.0.2.0-1
```

Then added the following to /etc/yum.conf to block updates:

```
exclude=msodbcsql
```

Then ran:

```
sudo /opt/sasbin/prox yum install php-sqlsrv-4.3.0
```

Everything seems in order now.

-Loom